# copying files in a network

Tags: networking, copy

I have three computers at my network: A, B and C.

I am working from A, where I have a X: unit and Y: unit. X: points to a shared folder from B. Y: point to a shared folder from C.

I want to copy a file from X: to Y:.
It is the same than I want to copy from B to C, but making the operation from A.

So the question is: Does traffic goes from B to C directly, or does the traffic goes from B to A and from A to C?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a question-and-answer site related to computer programming. Unless I am missing something, your question is unrelated to computer programming. You might have better luck at our sister site, http://superuser.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just use standard Windows copy tools, the traffic will from B to A and then from A to C.

Comment: what tools can do a copy from B to C, executing from A?